# How to livedata in Imageview src?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, imageview, android-livedata

My viewmodel:

```
init{
  updateWallPaper()
}

private var _wallpaper = MutableLiveData<Bitmap>()
    val wallpaper: LiveData<Bitmap>
        get() = _wallpaper
fun updateWallPaper() {
        val file = appCtx.getWallpaperFile()
        if(file.exists()) {
            _wallpaper.value = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)
        }
    }
```

and my home `Activity.xml`:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_main_home_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="324dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/sample_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:load="@{homeViewModel.wallpaper }" />
```

All I want to do is to change this image somewhere else, and the image src changes in real time.

I tried many ways but failed and I wonder how to apply live data to src.

It's normal to operate onresume, but every time I return to the home, this method runs, so I think it's a waste of memory, so I'm going to change it to binding live data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `LiveData<Drawable>` instead:

```
    private var _wallpaper = MutableLiveData<Drawable>()
    val wallpaper: LiveData<Drawable>
        get() = _wallpaper

    fun updateWallPaper() {
        val file = appCtx.getWallpaperFile()
        if(file.exists()) {
            _wallpaper.value = BitmapDrawable(resources, BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath))
        }
    }
```

then you can use `ImageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable)` from data binding XML (by using `app:imageDrawable` syntax):

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_main_home_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="324dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/sample_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:imageDrawable="@{homeViewModel.wallpaper }" />
```

Comment: @LeeDuSeop Wherever you want!